# Configure printer attached to router

Tags: router, printer

I have a Samsung M2675F printer/scanner/copier that worked ok being connected to my main desktop. Wanted to print from all my home computers, so I plugged the printer in my ASUS AC68U router (have 2 of them, working in AiMesh - printer is connected in the node router).
Installed the EX print driver, and then followed the steps[here](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/114024) Printer works ok, BUT printer status is not available, (samsung easy print manager is updated and shows that my printer is not connected). I cannot scan anything and don't find the option.
Printing works fine, even if the printer is sleeping, it wakes up and prints.
Can I do something to see all the options/to scan?

Comment: Is your printer on the same subnet as the computer you are printing on?  Can you install the Samsung complete printer package on this computer to get scanning functions? That should give you status as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's on the same subnet. Don't really know how to see...
After installing the Asus EZ printer, I have added a new printer, selected the tcp/ip address of my second router where the printer is plugged in and selected the driver from the list. That was all.
I already had the full "package" from Samsung and if i plug in the printer in my USB port I regain all the functions. If I plug it in the router, although I can print, the interface says that the printer is not connected and no status messages.
In printer properties I have selected bidirectional support, the driver is selected from the list (Samsung M267x 287x series).
Only difference is that advanced tab, under driver, I have the "samsung M267x 287x series" and under the same tab for the USB printer, it shows"samsung universal print driver 3" - don't know it this is an issue.

Comment: Get Advanced IP Scanner (Famatech and free). Install and run it. Go to the computer you are trying to print with. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. Run IPCONFIG. That gives you an IP address. Put this subnet (whole subnet) into Advanced IP Scanner and start the scan. Does the Printer show up?  Also you might wish to give your printer a Static IP on your network. It is possible the scanner software (two way software) is losing the printer .